# Vectors where $L^{1}$ norm of a matrix is greater than $L^{∞} $ norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I'm trying to figure out if there is a vector $x ∈ R^{d}
$ such that $||x||_{1}$= 100 and $||x||_{∞} = 1$. I need to either give an example of a vector or prove that no such vector exists.

I know that the $L^{1}$ norm of a vector x = $(x_{1},...,x_{d}) ∈ R^{d}$ is just $|x_{1}| + . . . + |x_{d}|$, and the $L^{∞}$ norm is the largest of the numbers. I'm not too sure where to start other than trying random vectors that only hold true for $L^{1}$ but not $L^{∞}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the defintions of the norms that $\|x\|_1 \leq d\|x\|_{\infty}$. So we cannot have such an $x$ if $100> d$. If $100 \leq d$ look at a vector of the form $(1,1,...,1,0,0,...)$.

Comment: I see, thanks! So If I were looking for a vector that satisfies $||x||_{1}$ = 1 and $||x||_{∞}$ = 2 we could have one if 2 ≤ d??

Comment: No, you need $1 \leq 2d$. But this is always satisfied since $d \geq 1$. @Axel